# No TUI support for gdb on Mac?

Tags: macos, gdb

I'm trying to use TUI mode in gdb on my Mac and for some reason it doesn't recognize the "-tui" flag.

I am about to install the latest version but as I can't find any mention of TUI not working in older versions, I was swondering if perhaps I'm doing it wrong.

How can I use TUI on my Mac?

Comment: Did you ever try the version of GDB provided by macports?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GDB can be built without tui, and this may be the case. Compile gdb for yourself, and enable TUI in configure.

Or, compile a cgdb, which is very like TUI.

How to install cgdb http://lists.apple.com/archives/Xcode-users/2009/Jul/msg00194.html Also this letter says:

> but the Apple gdb is built with this feature /TUI/ disabled.

Comment: Nice! And if you are using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/), it has a recipe for installing `cgdb` -- just do `brew install cgdb`