# gdb layout asm doesn't work on mac?

Tags: macos, gdb

```
$ gdb test

(gdb) start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000ec8
Starting program: /private/tmp/test 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +. done    
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000100000ec8 in main ()

(gdb) layout asm
Undefined command: "layout".  Try "help".

$ gdbtui
-bash: gdbtui: command not found
```

Is `layout` and `gdbtui` not available for `Mac OS X`? What are some alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No TUI support for gdb on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612133/no-tui-support-for-gdb-on-mac)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612133/no-tui-support-for-gdb-on-mac) there is no tui support on mac by default. So you have to compile gdb yourself with TUI enabled.