# GDB on AIX 6.1 has NO TUI mode?

Tags: c, gdb, aix

We have installed GDB on AIX 6.1 (gdb-6.0-1.aix5.1.ppc_AIX.rpm) and I notice that there is no "TUI" (terminal user interface) mode for "interactive source code debugging"?

Is that a known thing for GDB on AIX? Is there another way I can debug my application through the source code like using TUI mode on AIX? Perhaps using TTY somehow?

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen. GDB only has one user interface, and it's text-based. What are you doing, and what's happening?

Comment: If you run gdb ./<my program> -tui you will see that the source code comes up in the console as well....that is what I am after....thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need a more recent GDB. [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) is now at version **7.3.1** and gdb 7.2 has a `--tui` option.

Did you try to build GDB from its source code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a same problem in my Mac OS X 10.6.6, then I try to build gdb 7.3.1 from source code, finally get the --tui option. While I use command "gdb --tui program" and typed "run" to debug, I get this message:

```
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 36434: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
(please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

Then I use command "sudo gdb --tui program" to resolve it.

And there is a [cgdb](http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/) which based curses, and like TUI option. 
See also question [No TUI support for gdb on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612133/no-tui-support-for-gdb-on-mac)